# Extracting specific data from xml document with node and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I've fetched some data from a site and i want to sort it.

Specifically i want the value of the wind attribute.

How can i iterate over this data and extract only the value of the wind and the initial time that the data was fetched?

Below is an example of the data and my code (that doesn't work)

Thank you

```
   axios(config)
        .then(function (response)
        {


            // console.log(dataArray.length);
            fs.writeFile('/documents/hm.xml', response.data, (err) =>
            {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('The file has been saved!');
            });

            fs.readFile("/documents/hm.xml", (err, data) =>
            {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (window.DOMParser)
                {
                    parser = new DOMParser();
                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
                }
                console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("WIND")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue);

            })
            //response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/documents/hm.json"))
            return JSON.stringify(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Data example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GENERATION_BY_FUEL_TYPE_TABLE>
   <INST AT="2020-07-04 17:50:00" TOTAL="26065">
      <FUEL TYPE="CCGT" IC="N" VAL="6648" PCT="25.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OCGT" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OIL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="COAL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NUCLEAR" IC="N" VAL="5266" PCT="20.2"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="WIND" IC="N" VAL="7292" PCT="28.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="PS" IC="N" VAL="902" PCT="3.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NPSHYD" IC="N" VAL="964" PCT="3.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OTHER" IC="N" VAL="368" PCT="1.4"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTFR" IC="Y" VAL="1506" PCT="5.8"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTIRL" IC="Y" VAL="151" PCT="0.6"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNED" IC="Y" VAL="758" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTEW" IC="Y" VAL="338" PCT="1.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="BIOMASS" IC="N" VAL="1117" PCT="4.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNEM" IC="Y" VAL="755" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
    </INST>
    <HH SD="2020-07-04" SP="39" AT="18:00-18:30" TOTAL="26416">
      <FUEL TYPE="CCGT" IC="N" VAL="7692" PCT="29.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OCGT" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OIL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="COAL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NUCLEAR" IC="N" VAL="5277" PCT="20.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="WIND" IC="N" VAL="6780" PCT="25.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="PS" IC="N" VAL="732" PCT="2.8"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NPSHYD" IC="N" VAL="963" PCT="3.6"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OTHER" IC="N" VAL="352" PCT="1.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTFR" IC="Y" VAL="1506" PCT="5.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTIRL" IC="Y" VAL="152" PCT="0.6"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNED" IC="Y" VAL="756" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTEW" IC="Y" VAL="338" PCT="1.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="BIOMASS" IC="N" VAL="1112" PCT="4.2"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNEM" IC="Y" VAL="756" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
   </HH>
   <LAST24H FROM_SD="2020-07-03" FROM_SP="40" AT="18:30-18:30" TOTAL="558144">
      <FUEL TYPE="CCGT" IC="N" VAL="137632" PCT="24.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OCGT" IC="N" VAL="4" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OIL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="COAL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NUCLEAR" IC="N" VAL="126489" PCT="22.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="WIND" IC="N" VAL="189620" PCT="34.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="PS" IC="N" VAL="6208" PCT="1.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NPSHYD" IC="N" VAL="15214" PCT="2.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OTHER" IC="N" VAL="4469" PCT="0.8"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTFR" IC="Y" VAL="19018" PCT="3.4"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTIRL" IC="Y" VAL="327" PCT="0.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNED" IC="Y" VAL="11774" PCT="2.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTEW" IC="Y" VAL="2829" PCT="0.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="BIOMASS" IC="N" VAL="30752" PCT="5.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNEM" IC="Y" VAL="13808" PCT="2.5"></FUEL>
   </LAST24H>
   <LAST_UPDATED AT="2020-07-04 17:50:00"></LAST_UPDATED>
</GENERATION_BY_FUEL_TYPE_TABLE>
```

Comment: Your nodes mostly have the tag name of "FUEL", not "WIND".  You need to pull the FUEL nodes and check for an attribute called TYPE that has a value of "WIND".

Comment: You might want to look at XQuery to find just the FUEL nodes with TYPE="WIND".

Answer (score 0):

you can use camaro for this

```js
const xml = `
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GENERATION_BY_FUEL_TYPE_TABLE>
   <INST AT="2020-07-04 17:50:00" TOTAL="26065">
      <FUEL TYPE="CCGT" IC="N" VAL="6648" PCT="25.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OCGT" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OIL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="COAL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NUCLEAR" IC="N" VAL="5266" PCT="20.2"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="WIND" IC="N" VAL="7292" PCT="28.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="PS" IC="N" VAL="902" PCT="3.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NPSHYD" IC="N" VAL="964" PCT="3.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OTHER" IC="N" VAL="368" PCT="1.4"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTFR" IC="Y" VAL="1506" PCT="5.8"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTIRL" IC="Y" VAL="151" PCT="0.6"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNED" IC="Y" VAL="758" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTEW" IC="Y" VAL="338" PCT="1.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="BIOMASS" IC="N" VAL="1117" PCT="4.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNEM" IC="Y" VAL="755" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
    </INST>
    <HH SD="2020-07-04" SP="39" AT="18:00-18:30" TOTAL="26416">
      <FUEL TYPE="CCGT" IC="N" VAL="7692" PCT="29.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OCGT" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OIL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="COAL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NUCLEAR" IC="N" VAL="5277" PCT="20.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="WIND" IC="N" VAL="6780" PCT="25.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="PS" IC="N" VAL="732" PCT="2.8"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NPSHYD" IC="N" VAL="963" PCT="3.6"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OTHER" IC="N" VAL="352" PCT="1.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTFR" IC="Y" VAL="1506" PCT="5.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTIRL" IC="Y" VAL="152" PCT="0.6"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNED" IC="Y" VAL="756" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTEW" IC="Y" VAL="338" PCT="1.3"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="BIOMASS" IC="N" VAL="1112" PCT="4.2"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNEM" IC="Y" VAL="756" PCT="2.9"></FUEL>
   </HH>
   <LAST24H FROM_SD="2020-07-03" FROM_SP="40" AT="18:30-18:30" TOTAL="558144">
      <FUEL TYPE="CCGT" IC="N" VAL="137632" PCT="24.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OCGT" IC="N" VAL="4" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OIL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="COAL" IC="N" VAL="0" PCT="0.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NUCLEAR" IC="N" VAL="126489" PCT="22.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="WIND" IC="N" VAL="189620" PCT="34.0"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="PS" IC="N" VAL="6208" PCT="1.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="NPSHYD" IC="N" VAL="15214" PCT="2.7"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="OTHER" IC="N" VAL="4469" PCT="0.8"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTFR" IC="Y" VAL="19018" PCT="3.4"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTIRL" IC="Y" VAL="327" PCT="0.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNED" IC="Y" VAL="11774" PCT="2.1"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTEW" IC="Y" VAL="2829" PCT="0.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="BIOMASS" IC="N" VAL="30752" PCT="5.5"></FUEL>
      <FUEL TYPE="INTNEM" IC="Y" VAL="13808" PCT="2.5"></FUEL>
   </LAST24H>
   <LAST_UPDATED AT="2020-07-04 17:50:00"></LAST_UPDATED>
</GENERATION_BY_FUEL_TYPE_TABLE>`

const { transform } = require('camaro')

;(async function main() {
    const template = {
        fuels: ['//FUEL[@TYPE="WIND"]', {
            ic: '@IC',
            val: '@VAL',
            pct: '@PCT',
            parentAt: '../@AT',
            parentName: 'name(..)',
        }]
    }
    console.log(await transform(xml, template), null, 4);
})()
```

output

```
{
  fuels: [
    {
      ic: 'N',
      val: '7292',
      pct: '28.0',
      parentAt: '2020-07-04 17:50:00',
      parentName: 'INST'
    },
    {
      ic: 'N',
      val: '6780',
      pct: '25.7',
      parentAt: '18:00-18:30',
      parentName: 'HH'
    },
    {
      ic: 'N',
      val: '189620',
      pct: '34.0',
      parentAt: '18:30-18:30',
      parentName: 'LAST24H'
    }
  ]
}
```